# How to resolve pending promises within map returning an object?

Tags: javascript, promise

This would resolve all promises

```
const promises = files.map(filename => getPdfToPrint(`output\\${outputDirectory}\\` , filename.replace("/", "")));
const res = await Promise.all(promises)
```

but now the `files.map` function should map the filename to an object like this

```
const promises = files.map(filename => { return {status: getPdfToPrint(`output\\${outputDirectory}\\` , filename.replace("/", "")), filename: filename}});
const res = await Promise.all(promises)
```

in order to check whether the promise resolved "success" so that I know which files were retrieved and printed. But in this way the Promise resolving the status would still be pending.
How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `getPdfToPrint()` returns a promise. At the moment you're mapping each `filename` to the promise returned by `getPdfToPrint()`, but instead you want to have the resolved value in an object at the key `status` along with the `filename`. To achieve that, you can make your `.map()` callback `async`. This will do two things: firstly, it will enable you to `await` the `getPdfToPrint()` function Promise to get the resolved value so you can use that inside of the object you're returning. Secondly, it will make it so that your callback function returns a Promise (as all `async` functions return a Promise). This will allow you to use `Promise.all()` to detect once all the promises have resolved:

```
const promises = files.map(async filename => {
  const pdf = await getPdfToPrint(`output\\${outputDirectory}\\` , filename.replace("/", ""));
  return {status: pdf, filename}; 
});
const res = await Promise.all(promises);
```