# Pass second param when map urls with axios.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i have a array that contains a object with two values, like this:

```
[
 {
  brand: app1,  
  url: https://myhost.com/api
 },
 {
  brand: app2,  
  url: https://otherapi.com/api
 }
]
```

I'am using axios.all to made a get request over all urls, and I iterate it with a map, like this:

```
const getData= axios.all(stuffData.map((item) => axios.get(item.url)))
.then(res => console.log(res.data)
```

The thing is, how can I pass the second param in the array when i make the map to interate all axios requests? I also need pass the key "brand".

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71777378/5648954)? Note that `Promise.all()` should be used instead of `axios.all()` as `.all()` is deprecated.

Comment: I need get the response of axios request and get the brand stored in the mapped object stuffData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```js
Promise.all(stuffData.map(async (item) => ({ 
  data: await axios.get(item.url).data, 
  brand: item.brand
}))).then((data) => {
   data.forEach(item=> console.log(item))
})
```

Comment: thanks Tanay, that is just what i was looking for, +1

Comment: @Devp then please add a ✔ to my answer to close the loop